# ValueError: Unable to parse string "rock" at position 0

Tags: python, pandas

Estoy intentando convertir una columna de un dataframe a números y me aparece ese error,qué está pasando y cómo lo soluciono?

```
spotify_songs['playlist_genre'].replace({'pop':-2,'rock':-1,'rap':0,'r&b':0.5,'latin':1,'edm':2})
spotify_songs['playlist_genre'] = pd.to_numeric(spotify_songs['playlist_genre'])
```

Me da el siguente error:  `ValueError: Unable to parse string "rock" at position 0`

Answer (score 0):

Estás muy cerca, te falta guarda el replace en la misma columna:

```
spotify_songs['playlist_genre'] = spotify_songs['playlist_genre'].replace({'pop':-2,'rock':-1,'rap':0,'r&b':0.5,'latin':1,'edm':2})
```